# VF - Picklist of Accounts - Access selected value in controller

Tags: visualforce, selectlist, selectoption

I have my list populating correctly but I don't know how to get the ID value of the selected account back to my controller. Can someone tell me the correct syntax?

Useful bits of my controller:

```
String[] accounts = new String[]{};

public PageReference test() {
    return null;
}

public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    List<Account> acclist = new list<Account>();
    acclist = [Select ID, Name FROM Account];
    for(Account a:acclist){
        options.add(new SelectOption(a.Id,a.Name));
    }
    return options;
}

public String[] getAccounts() {
    return accounts;
}

public void setAccounts(String[] accounts) {
    this.accounts = accounts;
}
```

Here is my save operation. Trying to set the ID value for the record.

```
public void savenew() { 

            admintracking.Account__c = **?????????** 
//tried using accounts string but can't figure out syntax to use ID. 
        try {
            insert adminTracking;
        } catch(DmlException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: By your code, it looks like you want to get only one Account ID but in controller you have a list..

Comment: The VF page limits them to selecting one value from the list.

Comment: You should really share the *markup*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple approach here would be to use an [`<apex:selectList>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectList.htm) tag almost exactly as laid out in the documentation.

**Markup**

```
<apex:selectList value="{!accountId}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!accounts}" />
</apex:selectList>
```

**Code**

```
public String accountId { get; set; }
public List<SelectOption> accounts
{
    get
    {
        if (accounts == null)
        { // Lazy Load Pattern
            accounts = new List<SelectOption>();
            for (Account account : [SELECT Name FROM Account])
                accounts.add(new SelectOption(account.Id, account.Name));
        }
        return accounts;
    }
    private set;
}
```

From there, you would just use `adminTracking.Account__c = accountId`. Or you can change the markup to bind directly to `adminTracking.Account__c`, if you have exposed a getter for `adminTracking`.

```
<apex:selectList value="{!adminTracking.Account__c}">
```

Comment: On your For (Account...) line I am getting a "Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement." error.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax would look like this:-

```
public void savenew() { 

    if(accounts.size()==1) {
     admintracking.Account__c = accounts[0];
     //tried using accounts string but can't figure out syntax to use ID. 
        try {
            insert adminTracking;
        } catch(DmlException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This piece of code should work only if `accounts` has value in it.

Additionally, if you are expecting only one Id then change:-

```
String[] accounts = new String[]{};
```

to

```
String  accountId;
```

In `savenew` method you can simple access value as:-

```
admintracking.Account__c = accounId;
```